# Over or on, but not both

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I came up with this riddle this morning:

> I can be over or on, both cases
>   A cable is preferred but not required as power line
>   When used properly, I take you to other places
>   Sharing me is not possible, due to my design

**What am I?**

(Please keep in mind that this is my first riddle;
I'm totally open to advice on how to maybe rephrase this.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are:

> Ear/headphones

I can be over or on, both cases

> Over-ear vs on-ear headphones

A cable is preferred but not required as power line

> The ear/head phones could have batteries inside them, so the cable is not required

When used properly I take you to other places

> Music can take you to other places

Sharing me is not possible, due to my design

> Usually very small, although you could potentially share by giving the "other ear" to someone else

Comment: Well done, that was the answer I was looking for :D

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if this is the answer but I had to put it here:

> Toilet Paper:

I can be over or on, both cases

> The old debate
>  [image]

A cable is preferred but not required as power line

> I would rather have TP on a cable, or rod and or something, not just sitting there.

When used properly I take you to other places

> I'll let everyone imagine what this means in combination with my answer.

Sharing me is not possible, due to my design

> Well, you don't want to share it.

Comment: ... no. Just no.

Comment: Although this answer sure gave me a good laugh, sadly it is wrong!

Comment: Over. Always over.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, bummer, bg6471 beats me by 48seconds. I need to address my typing skills.

> My guess is HEADPHONES

I can be over or on, both cases

> There are over-the-years models, there are on-year models

A cable is preferred but not required as power line

> They could be cabled but also could be wireless

When used properly I take you to other places

> Music or radio take you to other places

Sharing me is not possible, due to my design

> Usually their design won't let more than one person to use them.